# Nearest neighbour in pyspark using euclidean distance or similar

Tags: python, pyspark, nearest-neighbor, knn

So I need to find nearest neighbors of a given row in pyspark DF using euclidean distance or anything. the data that I have 20+ columns, more than thousand rows and all the values are numbers.

I am trying to oversample some data in pyspark, as mllib doesn't have inbuilt support for it, i decided to create it myself using smote.

my approach till now has been to convert all the categorical distance into index using **stringtoindex** so that i can find the euclidean distance and neighbors and hence perform smote.

I am fairly new to spark and ml. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your *specific* problem? Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then, update and *improve your question*.

Comment: made some edits, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tried but Ive found this script: https://github.com/jakac/spark-python-knn/blob/master/python/gaussalgo/knn/knn.py

If your data are dataframe, you should first merge your column into a vector with vectorASsembler https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler, then use `df.select("id", "yourColumnVector")`

The library I provided seems to work only with rdd, so you should convert your dataframe to RDD using `df.rdd`